# How to connect USB to an ATmega328p?

Tags: usb, avr, usb-device

I'm making a board that requires an ATmega328P to respond to commands from a computer. It needs to be connected with USB. I am new to this and trying to figure out how to best do this. I know I'll need to use V-USB, but I still don't really know what pins on the ATmega to send the USB data to. If anyone has advice or recommended reading, please let me know!

And I apologize if the question is unclear. If you need more information, just ask :)

Comment: look at an Arduino Uno schematic

Comment: Use something newer than the 328p that has built in usb. Like the 32u4. You know something from this decade.

Comment: @jsotola Arduino Uno is a pretty bad reference design for this, as it adds the USB by adding **another** microcontroller. Probably one of the last things that OP would want to do.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny it will give the OP an idea how it can be done with the ATmega328P

Comment: Why don't you just drop in a NANO to your board? https://solderingmind.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/arduino-nano-schematics.png

Comment: If you happen to be using Arduino, you'd get hardware USB and good FW compatibility with Atmega32U4, which is being used in for example Arduino Leonardo.

Answer (score 3):

The first source of recommended reading for V-USB implementation would be V-USB itself.

If you download [V-USB from Obdev's website](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/download.html), it includes a folder with reference circuits and a Readme-file with additional information with some design notes.

I'll paste the general design notes from there below, for anyone interested that can't bother to download the package:

> All examples have D+ on hardware interrupt INT0 because this is the
> highest priority interrupt on AVRs. You may use other hardware
> interrupts (and configure the options at the end of usbconfig.h
> accordingly) if you make sure that no higher priority interrupt is
> used.
>
> If you use USB_SOF_HOOK or USB_COUNT_SOF in usbconfig.h, you must wire
> D- to the interrupt instead. This way the interrupt is triggered on
> USB Start Of Frame pulses as well.
>
> Most examples have a 1M pull-down resistor at D+. This pull-up ensures
> that in self-powered designs no interrupts occur while USB is not
> connected. You may omit this resistor in bus-powered designs. Older
> examples had a pull-up resistor instead. This is not compatible with
> the zener diode approach to level conversion: 1M pull-up in
> conjunction with a 3.6 V zener diode give an invalid logic level.
>
> All examples with ATMega8/88/168 have D+ at port D bit 2 (because this
> is hardware interrupt 0) and D- on port D bit 4 because it is also a
> clock input for timer/counter 0. This way the firmware can easily
> check for activity on D- (USB frame pulses) by checking the counter
> value in regular intervals. If no activity is found, the firmware
> should (according to the USB specification) put the system into a low
> power suspend mode.

If you want to go a probably easier route (although you probably won't learn as much) and BOM cost doesn't matter, you could consider using an [FTDI USB to Serial converter chip](https://ftdichip.com/product-category/products/ic/) instead. Then you can use UART to communicate with a virtual COM port on the PC that you connect your device to.

Or, you could use another microcontroller that has built in USB hardware and a supported USB software stack from its manufacturer.

Comment: Many arduino clones use USB to Serial converter CH340G, which doesn't even require own external crystal and works well enough, and doesn't require external circuitry. It requires drivers, which are freely available. For a small project would be a go-to, imo